# weblogic-maven-plugin: 12.2.1 - Failed to execute goal redeploy - artifact location not specified

Tags: maven-3, weblogic12c, weblogic-maven-plugin

I tried to deploy my application using maven weblogic plugin. I get the below error message  and not sure of what it means by 'artifact location not specified'.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin:12.2.1-1-0:redeploy (default-cli) on project mdm_client: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: The artifact location was not specified.
    [ERROR] at weblogic.tools.maven.plugins.BaseMojo.getArtifactFile(BaseMojo.java:112)
    [ERROR] at weblogic.tools.maven.plugins.deploy.RedeployMojo.populateParameters(RedeployMojo.java:297)
    [ERROR] at weblogic.tools.maven.plugins.deploy.RedeployMojo.execute(RedeployMojo.java:263)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
```

my application POM.xml

```
<!-- WebLogic Server 12c Maven Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
            <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.1-1-0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>wls-redeploy</id>
                    <phase>development build</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>redeploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <adminurl>t3://localhost:7001</adminurl>
                <middlewareHome>C:/Oracle/Middleware</middlewareHome>                   
                <domainHome>project</domainHome>

                <user>${user}</user>
                <password>${password}</password>
                <name>${name}</name>
                <remote>${remote}</remote>
                <upload>${upload}</upload>
                <targets>${targets}</targets>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
```

Comment: FYI the `<phase>development build</phase>` will simply be ignored and the whole execution would not occur, althought I believe this is not the problem you are currently experiencing. how are you invoking the weblogic plugin? via command line invocation?

Comment: I use the eclipse to run my maven command

Comment: And what did you typed in the Eclipse maven run configuration? simply `mvn weblogic:redeploy`? Is the `${name}` and other referenced properties defined in your `pom.xml` file or are they provided via command line?

Comment: 'clean install com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin:redeploy' this is my command which I run in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the  ear, jar, war in the configuration

[oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13702/maven_deployer.htm#DEPGD386)